# Using a Java Drawable as a notification icon

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-drawable

In an Android project, I have created a Java-based `Drawable` (to be more specific, a `LevelListDrawable`). This way I can create the icon dynamically from a value.

I have a level that covers all numbers and contains a `Drawable`. Then in that `Drawable` I draw a number, which in turn is set and redrawn by `onLevelChange`.

I would like to use that `LevelListDrawable` as an icon for a notification.

I made this XML file called `notif_icon.xml` that, I believe, should work as that Drawable.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my.app.package.MyDrawable />
```

Then I try to use that in my code:

```java
mNotif = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("Title")
    .setContentText("Message")
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif_icon, random)
    .build();
// And show it later... 
NotificationManager man = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
man.notify(1, mNotif);
```

But I get this:

> android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package my.app.package: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon(pkg=my.app.packageuser=0 id=0x7f020001 level=0 visible=true num=0 )

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you try doing that with a bitmap-based drawable?

Comment: @SargeBorsch No, I have to use a dynamic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be wrong?

Other processes have no means of accessing your app's custom views, drawables, or other custom classes. Hence, the OS process that renders the notification cannot access `my.app.package.MyDrawable`. That assumes that your XML syntax was correct, and I am not aware that you can create XML drawables from arbitrary classes that way (though I cannot rule it out, as I have not researched that point).

You are welcome to use a `<level-list>` drawable resource with a `RemoteViews`, but you cannot use a `LevelListDrawable` that you construct in memory, nor a custom subclass of `LevelListDrawable`.

Comment: All right. How would I go about having dynamic notification icons then?

Comment: @Pietu1998: You are welcome to use `setLargeBitmap()` and use a dynamically-created bitmap, but that may or may not be used in the status bar (depends upon device). `setIcon()`, which is used most of the time for the status bar, only accepts resources. You are certainly welcome to have several such resources in your app and choose one based upon some criteria, in addition to using the levels.